# "sometimes" is adjective or adverb

Tags: meaning, adjectives, adverbs, parts-of-speech

In this sentence:

> The sometimes patronizing, often demeaning portrayal of women—even supposedly liberated women—remained, though often clandestine or packaged in the language of liberation.

I think the `sometimes` is in the position of adjective, but in dictionary I couldn't find `sometimes` as adjective. what is the meaning of `sometimes` in this sentence as adjective?

or

An adverb can emerge in the noun phrase as same as this sentence?

[The downloadable document is here. (page 51, first paragaraph)](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=8&ved=0CFYQFjAH&url=http://m.friendfeed-media.com/1666b39312096f7bf2d75b37aac71dde3fb6cd21&ei=rkqpU_OYEtiWuATO6oD4CQ&usg=AFQjCNG3oSlH9CEgelQrAjAnRujmzlOGGg&sig2=XUyzHnabnRNPJrzG8U-k9Q)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, in this example, *patronizing* is the adjective. ***Sometimes* is (and always will be) an adverb**. Allow me to explain.

***Patronizing* is the *present participle* form of the verb** *patronize*. [Using the present participle turns a verb into an adjective](http://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/present_participle.htm). In this case, *patronizing* is being used as an adjective to describe *the portrayal of women*.

***Sometimes* is being used to modify *patronizing***. So what [part of speech](http://web2.uvcs.uvic.ca/ELC/STUDYZONE/330/grammar/parts.htm) is it? Well, it is being used to modify *patronizing*, which, even though it serves the function of an adjective, is still a verb by nature. **[A word that modifies a verb is an adverb](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/adverbs.htm).**

So we can come to this conclusion from two directions:

> 1. [By definition, *sometimes* is an adverb.](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/sometimes)
> 2. *Sometimes* is being used to modify a verb, *patronizing*. Therefore it is an adverb.

Comment: While this answer is correct, I believe some of your reasoning is not. *Sometimes* is not modifying a verb, it is modifying an adjective. A word that modifies an adjective is also an adverb. Just because the root form (*patronize*) is a verb does not mean it is always modified by an adverb. For example, if *patronizing* was a gerund, you would modify it with adjectives: "I always hated their *annoying patronizing*."

Comment: What @JakeKing said. To put it another way, *sometimes* would have the same part of speech if you replaced "patronizing" with, say, "blue". (The sentence wouldn't make much sense, but the grammar wouldn't change.)

Comment: @JakeKing I hear what you're saying, but it doesn't change the answer in any way. [By definition, a participle is the form of a verb that plays the role of an adjective](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Participle). In my answer, I recognized that *patronizing* is both a verb and an adjective. Yes, it is true that adverbs can modify both verbs and adjectives. So the end result is the same, *sometimes* is an adverb, regardless of whether you want to see *patronizing* as an adjective or a verb. I could have written all of that in the answer, but it would have done no good, and caused more confusion.

Comment: @Egghead99 You said this: "Well, it is being used to modify *patronizing*, which, even though it serves the function of an adjective, **is still a verb by nature**." (emphasis mine) *That* is the part that I disagree with. The word *patronizing* is not a verb, it *is* an adjective. It's derived from a verb, but that does not change its part of speech.

Comment: @Egghead99 Again, note that [Wikipedia describes a gerund](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerund) as "a non-finite verb form," but a gerund is a *noun,* and you use adjectives to describe nouns, not adverbs. The relevant piece of information is the functional part of speech, not the word's derivation.

Comment: @JakeKing What you said is technically true, but I still believe that it's outside the scope of the OP's question and therefore outside the scope of the answer. In OP's example, *patronizing* is a participle, not a gerund. Remember that we're in English Language *Learners*. Many of our question askers are just starting to grasp the language, so we should try to frame our answers in a way that easy to understand for beginners, not bog them down with details and nuances. If you still feel strongly about it, please either suggest an edit, or we can get a chat room and hash one out.

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure that sentence is punctuated as in the original source? I would have expected it to be written as:

> The sometimes-patronizing, often-demeaning portrayal...

[Sometimes](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/sometimes?s=t) is being used as an adverb here, because it's modifying "patronizing" (which is itself being used as a modifier: it describes the type of portrayal). I am used to seeing this with a hyphen when used in series with another adverb-of-frequency like "often", but it isn't required when used individually. ([Here](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=%22The%20sometimes%20irritating%20%22)'s some examples).

Comment: I added source document, I double checked and my punctuation is as same as original punctuation.

Comment: I'd say that the hyphens are optional but the comma after "patronizing" is definitely needed.

Answer (score 1):

As other answers have noted, "sometimes" is used as an adverb in the cited text.  It may be worth noting, however, that many because many nouns are sometimes used as adjectives and not all uses are noted, "sometimes" may be sometimes be used to modify things which look like nouns but really aren't.  For example, one may refer to a cafeteria's "sometimes-beef, sometimes-pork, mystery-meat pies" [both "beef" and "pork" would be adjectives in that sentence, modifying "pies", so "sometimes" would be an adverb even though it would appear to be modifying nouns.

Additionally, it's worth noting that "sometime" may be legitimately used as an adjective, and that use of "sometimes" in the same fashion, whether legitimate or not, is hardly unknown.